# Will a tube smaller than the tire be compatible?

Tags: innertube

I have a e-scooter with 10" by 2.50" wheels that needs a tube. Will a 10" by 2" tube be compatible with the tire? Or do I need to purchase one with the same size as the tire? Please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Most tubes specify a RANGE of widths they accommodate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertain to a e-scooter with 10" wheels, not a bicycle.

Comment: Closing as duplicate of the tube question.  Even though this may be an electric scooter and not a pedal bicycle, the tube/sizing information is reasonably similar.  Otherwise the question might be better on Motorcycles.SE